# Vue.js pass data from slot into component instance

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I'm trying to build a re-usable component to deal with submitting forms via AJAX using Vue.js. Ideally, what I want to do is have a generic component that can be used in place of a HTML `form` element, in that may contain an unknown set of form elements such as `input`, `select`, `textarea` and so on.

I have got the following code for my component which is named `ajax-form`:

```
<template>
    <form class="form" :action="action" :method="method" v-on:submit.prevent="ajaxSubmit">
        <slot></slot>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    props: {
        action: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        method: {
            default: 'post',
            required: false,
            type: String
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            formData: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ajaxSubmit() {
            // Do ajax
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And in my HTML, I would have something like the following:

```
<ajax-form action="http://example.com/do/something">
    <input name="first_name" type="text">
    <textarea name="about_you"></textarea>
</ajax-form>
```

What I would ideally like to happen is have all of the form elements that are placed inside my component using it's slot to be mapped to the `data.formData` property in my Vue component instance. So in this case, the `data` property would look like:

```
data: {
    formData: {
        first_name: '',
        about: ''
    }
}
```

If I was to add another field to the component in my HTML, I would expect that to also be mapped to the Vue instance's `data` property.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Is there a way that I can tell Vue, when putting my form elements into the component via the slot, that I want this element to be mapped to something in the component's `data`?

I have tried adding `v-model` and `v-bind` on each form element to see if it that would somehow pass the data into the component's data:

```
<ajax-form action="http://example.com/do/something">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" v-model="formData.first_name">
</ajax-form>
```

However, Vue complains that reactive data properties must be declared before they're used in the template:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "formData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: I wonder if you could use the `mounted` (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) method to get a reference to the DOM element that Vue creates, and then iterate over it's children (using jQuery?) and add reactive properties to `this.data` via `Vue.set` (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: check this pen out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evYzOv?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. @PatrickSteele I tried your suggestion but couldn't get any further. I'm beginning to think it's not possible. The documentation seems to state this here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties. @ShekharJoshi I'm not sure you understand my question. I can't know the contents of the slot ahead of time, I want to be able to create reactive bindings between the elements passed into my component via the slot and items of my `data`. Your suggestion assumes that I know what the data etc. is going to be ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking as the slots scope is limited to the parent scope.

You can define formData on the global Vue instance, so it is now accessible from the parent scope.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        formData : {}
    }
});
```

Now you can pass it to the form as a prop:

```
<ajax-form action="#" :form-data="formData>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" v-model="formData.first_name">
</ajax-form>
```

Comment: Perfect. I get the feeling Vue won't let me do it the way I want with just a component passing in the data from the slot, but this is a nice workaround.

Comment: The problem is also nicely solvable by using scoped slots. Without any hacks. As described in [blockhead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43543107/2016383)

Answer (score 34):

You can do this with scopedSlots.

The api looks like this:

```
<ajax-form action="http://example.com/do/something">
   <template scope="{formData}">    
   <input name="first_name" type="text" v-model="formData.first_name">
   </template>
</ajax-form>
```

And in the `ajax-form` component:

```
<form class="form" :action="action" :method="method" v-on:submit.prevent="ajaxSubmit">
   <slot :formData="formData">
</form>
```

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! This really helped me understand scoped slots, as the documentation doesn't give any real-world examples. Also, note that since Vue 2.5 the `scope` attribute is deprecated in favour of  `slot-scope`, which can be used on any element, not just `template`. So in this example you could have `<input name="first_name" type="text" v-model="formData.first_name" slot-scope="{ formData }">` instead of wrapping the input in a template tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But vue 2.6 is updated for syntax using scoped slots.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the data from **parent** to **child** as a parameter as follow:

*In the Parent:*

```html
<child-component ref="child">
      <h1 slot="heading">Test passing data to child</h1>
      <form slot="content">
          <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="Type your name" class="half">
          <input type="text" v-model="email" placeholder="Type your email" class="half">
          <div class="actions">
              <button data-role="submit" @click.prevent="callAddRep($event)">Add</button>
          </div>
      </form>
</child-component>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    callAddRep: function(e) {

      let name = this.name,
          email = this.email

      this.$refs.child.addRep(e, {
          name,
          email
      })
  }
```

*In the Child:*

```js
methods: {
      addRep: function(e, data) {

          //Data passed successfully
          console.log(data)

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While @blockhead's answer is correct, it's important to note that it doesn't matter if the slot inserted into ajax-form is a single file component with own template tag. You will still have to wrap that component in an outer template tag in order to intercept the slot properties, and then pass them as properties into your actual target component

```
<modal-two modal_id="notif-modal">

    <template #default="{id_for_children}">

        <notification-alert :parent_modal_name="id_for_children" />
    </template>
</modal-two>
```

I didn't see this anywhere else